# Difference on core plot CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation and CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip?

Tags: iphone, core-plot, cptbarplot

I'm new to core plot and wondering what the difference is on `CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation`  and `CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip`. I have been looking at the core plot example `CPTTestApp_ipadViewController` and I have seen that both of these field enum are called during filling the ploy with the `numberForPlot`-method but I don't understand the difference.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 4):

The difference is very huge. If we look at definition of type `CPTBarPlotField` in `CPTBarPlot` we will see that there are three values in that enum:

1. `CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation` : **Bar location on independent coordinate axis.**
2. `CPTBarPlotFieldBarTip` : **Bar tip value.**
3. `CPTBarPlotFieldBarBase`  : **Bar base (used only if barBasesVary is YES).**

You can ask - where can I use that values? Ok, you should use this constants in method `-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index`. In that method you should return values of that properties for each individual bar. For example,

```
-(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index 
{       
    int plotIndex = [(NSNumber *)plot.identifier intValue];
    return [[[datas objectAtIndex:plotIndex] objectAtIndex:index] valueForKey:(fieldEnum == CPTBarPlotFieldBarLocation ? @"x" : @"y")];
}
```

In my example I have dictionary which contains values for *x* axis (locations of bars) and *y* (values of bars).

I want to mention, that you should not set property `plotRange` of your `CPTBarPlot *plot` or `CorePlot` will set locations of your bars automatically (at position 0,1,2,3,4....).